# XPATH: how get .length of 1st element group and .length of 2nd element group inside 1st group?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, traversal

I'm working with xml files having the structure set out below.

`<GroupType1>` and `<GroupType2>` need to be processed separately.

In either case, I want to loop through the `<OperationEvent>` elements in each `<OperationStage>` using XPATH.

So, for each `<GroupType1>`, I need to get the number of `<OperationStage>` in `<OperationStageCollection>`, then get the number of `<OperationEvent>` in the `<OperationEventCollection>` of the current `<OperationStage>`.

In pseudocode, the processing would be:

```
    For i = 1 to number of <OperationStageCode> in current <OperationStage> of current <GroupType1>
        For j = 1 to number of <OperationEvent> in ith <OperationStage> in the current <GroupType1>
            process jth <OperationEvent> of ith <OperationStage>
        Next J
    Next i
```

And then I'd do the same for `<GroupType2>`

I'm stuck trying to get the number of `<OperationStage>` in `<OperationStageCollection>`, and the number of `<OperationEvent>` in the `<OperationEventCollection>` of the current `<OperationStage>`.

I've tried various expressions, like:

```
i = xDOC.selectNodes("//OperationStage").length
```

But of course that just gets the total number of `<OperationStage>` in the entire `<GroupCollection>`.  The other expressions I've tried (below) all return zero.  As you can see, I'm just flailing here--exposing my lack of familiarity with XPATH traversal syntax.

```
i = xDOC.selectNodes("/OperationStage").length
i = xDOC.selectNodes("OperationStageCollection//catmk:ProceedingStage").length
i = xDOC.selectNodes("OperationStageCollection/catmk:ProceedingStage").length
i = xDOC.selectNodes("/OperationStageCollection/catmk:ProceedingStage").length
```

What is the correct syntax to get the number of `<OperationStage>` in `<OperationStageCollection>` of a single `<GroupType1>`, then get the number of `<OperationEvent>` in the `<OperationEventCollection>` of the current `<OperationStage>`?

I've looked at a lot of XPATH documentation, but I haven't found anything with useful examples in the ballpark of my situation.  Please also point me to such documentation if you're aware of it.

Here's the xml structure:

```xml
<GroupCollection>
    <Groups>
        <GroupType1>
            <GroupType1_Identifier>1</GroupType1_Identifier>
            <OperationStageCollection>
                <OperationStage>
                     <OperationStageCode>3</OperationStageCode>
                        <OperationEventCollection>
                            <OperationEvent>
                                <OperationEventDate1>2018-12-16</OperationEventDate1>
                                <OperationEventCode>5</OperationEventCode>
                                <OperationEventDate2>2018-05-16</OperationEventDate2>
                            </OperationEvent>
                            ... more OperationEvents ...
                        </OperationEventCollection>
                </OperationStage>
                ... more OperationStages ...
            </OperationStageCollection>
        </GroupType1>
        ...moreGroupType1...
         <GroupType2>
            <GroupType2_Identifier>3</GroupType2_Identifier>
            <OperationStageCollection>
                <OperationStage>
                    <OperationStageCode>101</OperationStageCode>
                        <OperationEventCollection>
                            <OperationEvent>
                                <OperationEventCode>6</OperationEventCode>
                                <OperationEventDate2>2012-01-03</OperationEventDate2>
                            </OperationEvent>
                            ... more OperationEvents ...
                        </OperationEventCollection>
                </OperationStage>
                ... more OperationStages ...
            </OperationStageCollection>
        </GroupType2>
        ...moreGroupType2...
    </Groups>
</GroupCollection>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly in terms of xpath expressions, I believe

```
//GroupType1/OperationStageCollection/count(OperationStage)
```

should get you the number of `<OperationStage>`s in `<OperationStageCollection>` of a single `<GroupType1>` and

```
//GroupType1/OperationStageCollection/OperationStage//OperationEventCollection/count(OperationEvent)
```

should get you the number of `<OperationEvent>`s in the `<OperationEventCollection>` of the current `<OperationStage>`.

Comment: Jack: Thank you.  The first part works, but the second part is giving me the number of `<OperationEvent>`s in the entire `<OperationStageCollection>`; not just the number of `<OperationEvent>`s in the `<OperationEventCollection>` of the current `<OperationStage>`.  I'll keep fiddling with it to see if I can get it to work, but if you can suggest a tweak in the meantime I'd appreciate it.  I still don't fully grasp the syntax.  I thought that "//" captured every specified element in the entire xml document, but I see that's wrong since you're using "//" in the middle of the string of elements.

Comment: @BRW - That must be something in your implementation. I tried it again in different online xpath testers and the output is always the number in the current `<OperationEventCollection>`.

Comment: Jack:  A minor complication is that I have to code my implementation in VB6, which doesn't appear to support the count() method.  So, I've substituted .length, thus:

Comment: xDOC.selectNode("//GroupType1/OperationStageCollection/OperationStage//OperationEventCollection/OperationEvent").length

Comment: @BRW - It's all good as long as you get to where you want to be!

Comment: See [my related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58576564/how-evaluate-concatenated-string-as-indexed-xpath-expression-in-vb6?noredirect=1#comment103502946_58576564) which includes a comment showing how I managed to select child nodes relative to an indexed group of nodes.