# How evaluate concatenated string as indexed XPath expression in VB6

Tags: xpath, vb6, concatenation, evaluation

I've built an Xpath expression by concatenating strings in VB6:

```
    strXPath = "xDOC.selectNodes(" & """/GroupType1""" & ").item(" & CStr(i) & ").selectNodes(" & """/OperationStageCollection/OperationStage""" & ").length"
```

"i" is an integer used to index into

I want to evaluate strXPath to get a loop counter, for example:

```
    n = CInt(strXPath)
```

n is declared as Integer; strXPath is declared as string.  VB6 throws a Type Mismatch error on the above evaluation expression.  I must be missing something obvious.  How can I evaluate strXPath?

I realize that there may be errors in the XPath expression itself, but I'd like to get the evaluation working in order to debug such possible errors.

Comment: *"I've built an XPath expression by concatenating strings in VB6:"* - No, you have built **VB6 code** by concatenating strings. This won't work, and you *really* don't want to evaluate that.

Comment: Show your XML and describe what you want to achieve, instead of only describing *how* you want to achieve something that you did not explain itself.

Comment: You're right--I led myself down a dead end rabbit hole with the concatenated string approach.  I got onto that approach after reading another post that I can't quickly locate now, but I probably misconstrued it anyway.  In my comment to @Hel below I've indicated what seems to work.

Comment: FWIW, `xDOC.selectNodes("/GroupType1").item(i).selectNodes("/OperationStageCollection/OperationStage").Length` and `xDOC.selectNodes("/GroupType1[" & (i+1) & "]/OperationStageCollection/OperationStage").Length` should be the same (XPath counts from 1, VB counts from 0, hence the `+1`)

Comment: Noted.  Thank you.  I am gradually figuring this out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing some of the double-quotes:

```
iLength = xDOC.selectNodes("/GroupType1").item(i).selectNodes("/OperationStageCollection/OperationStage").length
```

This should return the `length` property you want, as an Integer.

Then you can use `iLength` in your loop.

Comment: Thanks Étienne.  That's exactly what I was doing before I decided to try the concatenated string approach.  I wondered if the index value was actually being evaluated, since the XPath expression returned 0 no matter how I adjusted the expression.  Now I'm wondering if it's OK to have 2 selectNodes in 1 expression.  The compiler accepts it, but I get 0 nodes.  You can see my xml in my related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530466/xpath-how-get-length-of-1st-element-group-and-length-of-2nd-element-group-ins).

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because you got me back on the right track.  In my comment to @Hel below I've indicated the small change that seems to work.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! Troubleshooting XPath can be tedious but you had added an extra layer of complexity! Good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 0):

@BRW: both of your questions are very specific, i.e. *how* to achieve certain results using XPath. But I have the suspicion that if you would explain *what* (data) you try to retrieve form the XML, commenters might show you ways you didn't think of, e.g. say you want to iterate through all `<OperationEvent>`s within a `<OperationEventCollection>`, a single `<OperationEvent>` can be retrieved by `//GroupType1/OperationStageCollection/OperationStage/OperationEventCollection/OperationEvent[1-based-index]`, e.g. `//GroupType1/OperationStageCollection/OperationStage/OperationEventCollection/OperationEvent[1]`, which results in a single XML node:

```
 <OperationEvent>
      <OperationEventDate1>2018-12-16</OperationEventDate1>
      <OperationEventCode>5</OperationEventCode>
      <OperationEventDate2>2018-05-16</OperationEventDate2>
 </OperationEvent>
```

So instead multiple `selectNodes` methods, *one* proper XPath query might yield the desired outcome right away.

Comment: Thanks Hel.  I think I have figured it out.     
`xDOC.selectNodes("/GroupType1").item(i).selectNodes(".//OperationStageCollection/OperationStage").length` gives me the correct result.  What I need to do is work with children relative to the indexed nodes, which `.//` seems to get me.